# Hide files in upper folder levels from home (FTP)

Tags: linux, ftp, proftpd

How to hide files in upper levels from home directory?

## Home folder of user `ftpuser`

```
/var/www/ftpuser
```

When the user `ftpuser` login on the FTP he can see all upper levels of the filesystem? The "start" folder level is `/var/www/ftpuser`.. How to change that to something like `/` so the user can't move up in the filesystem

```
# useradd ftpuser -p upload -d /var/www/ftpuser -s /bin/false
# passwd ftpuser
```

Comment: Off-topic for SO; belongs on [sf]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most FTP servers allow you to "chroot" your FTP root directory, on either/both a "default" and/or per-user basis.

Here is a good tutorial; your mileage will vary depending on platform and FTP server package you're using:

- http://www.faqs.org/docs/securing/chap29sec296.html